# Configure IIS 6 website SSL port programmatically?

Tags: iis-6

I am trying to configure the website SSL port with the certificate for a website within IIS 6.0 programmatically.

IIS 7.0 provides the API, ServerManager, to do so, but I am not sure if there is something similar for IIS 6.0 or command line utilities.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean just setting the port NUMBER programmatically, you can use the metabase command line tool (by default in C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts):

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/securebindings ":nnn:"
```

where nnn is the port number (e.g., ":443:"). (If you have more than one site on the server, you will need to substitute w3svc/x/securebindings, where x is the web site ID.)

If you actually need to install the CERTIFICATE programmatically, from what I gather there's a script in the [IIS 6.0 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56FC92EE-A71A-4C73-B628-ADE629C89499&displaylang=en) to do it (IISCertDeploy.vbs) but I've not tried it.

Comment: Oh Excellent!! how about set up the SSL certificate name associate with it?

Comment: I believe this is what IISCertDeploy.vbs is supposed to do, although again I haven't tried it so you may have to play around with it.

Comment: I found something interesting and thought share with you.
after setting up the ssl port of the site as you mentioned above, all I need to do is to use httpcfg to set ssl for the same port. In IIS website, it will show port is with the right cert. Thanks.